# Statistics throwing a die

Tags: statistics, dice

Sue and Tim play the following game. They throw a fair die alternately, starting with sue and the winner is first to obtain a 6.

Find the probability that Sue wins with her second throw

The answer in the mark scheme is 5/6 x 5/6 x 1/6
and Im not sure how they got this
Any help would be greatful

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the first throw of Sue is not a $6$ is $\frac56$. Then the probability that the first throw of Tim is not a $6$ is again $\frac56$.

And then the probability that for the second throw of Sue she gets a $6$ is $\frac16$.

So the total probability that all these things happen in a row is $\frac56\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac16$.